# Accessing an index of an array which is passed as a variable and increment the index value

Tags: mule, dataweave

I have an arrayList value1,value2,value3,value4 etc.I want to access the value as a variable i.e. vars.value[passing the index as a variable]. I want to increment the value once I access the first index

Answer (score 0):

The tricky part here is that after you create data with DataWeave, it becomes read-only. So while it's easy to access elements in an array by index even if the index is a var:

```
var ss = ["hello", "world"]
var n  = 1
---
ss[n] 
// Output: "World"
```

you can't modify it like this:

```
ss[n] = "new value"
```

You can do what you'd like to do in one of two ways. If you don't care about the order of the array, you can remove an element (which returns a new array without the element you removed), and add a new element to the end (again, returning a new array)

```
var ss = ["hello", "world"]
var n  = 0
---
(ss - n) + "space"
// Output: ["world", "space"]
```

If you do care about the order, your best option is `map`, I think. But you will have to check if the index matches up with the var for every iteration, and you need to complete the entire iteration through the input array:

```
var ss = ["hello", "world"]
var n  = 0
---
["hello", "world"] map (s, idx) ->
  if (idx == n) "goodbye" else s
// Output: ["goodbye", "world"]
```

Here's a more concrete example of what you're trying to achieve, using numbers instead of strings:

```
var ns                = [1,2,3,4,5]
var indexToIncrement  = 0
---
ns map (n, idx) -> 
  if (idx == indexToIncrement) n + 1 else n
// Output: [2,2,3,4,5]
```

Comment: Hi Jerney, Thank you for the response. Is there a way it can be done in Set Variable snippet where I want to use something like this : vars.a[vars.index] where I want to initialize index to 0 and increment it accordingly

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve this by initializing the variable with value #[0] and to increment it was done like #[vars.variable + 1]